# extracting chunk of string that matches regular expression using sed in unix

Tags: regex, unix, sed

Suppose I have a bunch of URLs and each URL contains an unique identifier. It looks like 'abc1000002'. It has the same leading string, 'abc', and only the number digits are different.

The identifier occurs in various positions in URLs,

http://www.examle.com?abc1000002
http://www.example.com?abc1000002=blahblah#3fdslfkj

I can write a regular expression like, 'abc[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]..[0-9], but how do I write a sed command to only extract the chunk that matches the regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

`grep` is better tool for this job:

```
s='http://www.example.com/?abc1000002=blahblah#3fdslfkj'
grep -Eo 'abc[0-9]+' <<< "$s"
abc1000002
```